# Web service request time out issue

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to interact with a web service, and for this purpose I am using this code.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://192.168.2.51/loodappSrv/LoodAppsrv.svc/company/insertcompany?Validation_Token=dc6f3d5e-22c7-405f-abb6-4491de140e7e");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = @"text/json";
JsonComapnyFormat jcf = new JsonComapnyFormat();
string data = jcf.data();//data in json Format {"companyName":"Alpha","departmentId":3}


using (Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    StreamWriter streamWriter = null;

    try
    {
        //streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

        streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        streamWriter.Write(data);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            streamWriter.Close();
            requestStream.Close();
            streamWriter.Dispose();
            streamWriter = null;
            requestStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
ViewBag.ABC = result;
return View();
```

If I Use Fiddler to send POST data on the given URL, it is perfect (sudden response comes out). But when I send same date on the same URL then the message return in an exception "The operation has timed out" at `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();`. Please suggest solutions.

Comment: Get rid of all of your `try`, `catch`, and `finally` blocks, and use `using`.

Comment: Your `Content-Type` is wrong.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/34397

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried what SLaks mentioned ?

The MIME media type for JSON text is **application/json**.

As can be seen [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type/477819#477819)